# How we achieve abstraction in java?

Tags: java, abstraction

As per definition, abstraction is hiding the implementation detail and revealing only the functionality. But exactly, what, where and which part we are hiding?

AFAIK the following program is an example of Abstraction:

```
public interface ToBeImplemented { 

   public string doThis();
}

public class Myclass implements ToBeImplemented {

@override
public string doThis() {

//Implementation

 return null;
 }
}
```

If I am wrong and this is not abstraction then what is the correct example of Abstraction?

Comment: That's one way of thinking about abstraction.  Not wrong; not all there is.

Comment: @duffymo can you help me understand what else is included in abstraction?

Comment: Is Google not installed on your machine?  What have you read?  What research have you done?

Comment: Ok i will google it. Thanks for your suggestion. Moreover, i asked for help and you helped by not giving the answer. People when google for question even google recommends for stackoverflow.

Comment: I think objects provide encapsulation and abstraction when you can look at  a function name or API and understand what it's doing without worrying about how it does it.  If I'm given a Matrix class, I can understand what its add() method does without worrying about how the author implemented it underneath.  If I use the java.util.List interface, I can concentrate on the methods it provides without worrying about how they are implemented.  It's a way to manage complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the above example you can write something like this:

```
public interface ToBeImplemented { 

    public string doThis();
}

public class ImplementationA implements ToBeImplemented {

    @override
    public string doThis() {

    //ImplementationA of doThis

    return null;
    }
}

public class ImplementationB implements ToBeImplemented {

    @override
    public string doThis() {

        //ImplementationB of doThis

        return null;
    }
```

}

Then you can have another class, and a main method for example:

```
class SomeClass{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ToBeImplemented someImplementation;

        //now you can pick an implementation, based on user input for example
        if (userInput == something) 
           someImplementation = new ImplementationA();
        else
           someImplementation = new ImplementationB();

        //do some staff

        //Regardless of the user input, main method only knows about the
        //abstract "ToBeImplemented", and so calls the .doThis() method of it
        //and the right method gets called based on the user input.
        someImplementaion.doThis();
        //at That

    }

}
```

The abstraction is that you can declare a ToBeImplemented reference, and then assign to it either ImplementationA, or ImplementationB (and possibly any other implementation). But you write your code against the abstract ToBeImplemented, and let some conditions decide what the right implementation of ToBeImplemented (and, as a result doThis()) should be called.

Answer (score 2):

Your definition of abstraction is correct. And the code you provided is definitely a form of abstraction.

Why?

Because the user of your code will only be provided with the interface. The user will only know that your code `doThis()` does a certain task but he/she won't know how the code does that certain task.

For example:

```
public interface myInterface{
 public int sumTo(n);
}

public class myClass implements myInterface{
 public int sumTo(int n){
  int sum=0;
  for(int i=0; i<=n; i++){
    sum+=i;
  }
  return sum;
 }
}
```

In this example, the user will only get the interface so he/she only knows that your code can sum up to *n*. But the user won't know that you used a for loop to sum up to *n*.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia is a good place to start your learning: [Abstraction (computer science)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(computer_science))

> The essence of abstractions is preserving information that is relevant in a given context, and forgetting information that is irrelevant in that context.
>
> John V. Guttag

Separating interface from implementation is *one* way to provide abstraction.

The [Collections framework in Java](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework) is an excellent example. Calling apps work with variables (references) declared as the interface such as [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) or [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) while the actual object in play is really a concrete class such as [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

If the interface provides all needed functionality, then there is no need for the calling app to know about the underlying implementation.

The example code shown in the Question is an example of separating interface from implementation, and therefore of abstraction. That example would be greatly improved if it used a specific meaningful context such as `BankAccount` as the interface and `SavingsAccount` and `CheckingAccount` as the implementations.

Comment: Can you provide me an article or writing which briefly explains how abstraction is achieved throw abstract class and interface in Java.


I can not co-relate how overriding an abstract method provides abstraction (hiding unnecessary details and provide only meaningful stuff). My understanding might be unclear.